# Compiling kernel module at root

Tags: kernel-module

So I have a typical hello world kernel module and the corresponding Makefile placed under root, and when I tried to compile by typing make, I get the following error:

> scripts/Makefile.build:128: kbuild: Makefile.build is included improperly

However, if I do it under a home subdirectory, everythig compiles just fine.

Below are the content of hello.c:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

static int __init hello_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Goodbye\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");
```

and Makefile:

```
obj-m += hello.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Can someone explain the reasons for this behavior?

Comment: What exact commands/makefile you use for compile module? Where is your module placed when you compile it under root?

Comment: I apologize for the poorly phrased question, I have edited the question accordingly.